Serving a static web application from a different absolute path on a different path of the domain
Ubuntu 20.04 :
I have a django application running on port 8000 and NGINX running in the foreground.
I have a docusaurus folder converted documentation at /home/myUsername/uploads/docs/ which is a pure static web application.
My nginx conf at /etc/nginx/conf.d/myProject.conf is as follows :
server {
        listen 80;
#       not used
}

########################
###HTTPS CONFIG#########
########################

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myProject.com;

        location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        client_max_body_size 100m;
        }

        location /sop/ {
           alias /home/myUsername/uploads/docs/;
           index index.html index.htm;
           try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
        }
#SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/myProject_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myProject_com.key;
}

But https://myProject.com/sop/ is returning an nginx 404. What's wrong with my config that it's unable to serve index.html from /home/myUsername/uploads/docs/ ?
